# Hard drive is detected but cannot mount when try to install ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive

When i tried to install ubuntu using usb flash i started receiving this error.
I can run ubuntu from usb and when i run ubuntu its shows my hard drive but when i try to mount hard drive its shows cannot mount hard drive.
My hard drive shows in boot menu but in ubuntu installation menu the installation stuck in phase of detecting hard drive section.
Now my hard disk is not working and i have some important pictures of my family in that drive can anyone help what i need to do?

```
[51.473986] print req_error : I/O error, dev sda, sector 1024000 flag 80700
[71.298386] print req_error : I/O error, dev sda, sector 1024000 flag 000
```

Comment: What "this" error?

Comment: I have mentioned error in comment please help as soon as possible.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you did in details and when you got this error.

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test on your storage hardware to rule in/out hardware failure

Comment: I have WD 500 gb hard drive in intel i3 and Intel motherboard. How to run SMART test in that?

Comment: status please...

Comment: I have ordered new sata cable so that i can check if there is not any problem due to my sata cable. I will update question after 19 dec. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got one or more bad blocks on the HDD, or the HDD is failing.

First, bring up the `Disks` app, go to `SMART Data & Tests`, and run the tests. Post the results as an edit to your question. Then look at the `SMART Data` window, and post screenshot(s). It may take two screenshots to capture all of the data for me to review.

After I review the SMART information, you may need to bad block the HDD, **but wait until I give the go-ahead.**

Second, to bad block the disk, and if the HDD is empty, or you have the data backed up elsewhere, use `gparted` to install a fresh MBR or GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive), and then create one large ext4 partition, and then follow these instructions to bad block the disk...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: My hard disk was faulty. After installing new hard drive now i have successfully installed ubuntu. Thanks everyone for helping me.